# Непонятное поведение spinner в dialogFragment

Tags: android, android-spinner

Имеется три разных спиннера которые размещены в dialogFragment. Эти спиннеры имеют собственную кастомную разметку и данные в них передаются из фрагмента. Передача осуществляется при помощи bundle в фрагменте:

```
FullScreenDialog dialog = new FullScreenDialog();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArrayList("sp1_1", (ArrayList<String>) title1);
bundle.putStringArrayList("sp1_2", (ArrayList<String>) count1);
bundle.putStringArrayList("id1", (ArrayList<String>) id1);
bundle.putStringArrayList("sp2_1", (ArrayList<String>) title2);
bundle.putStringArrayList("sp2_2", (ArrayList<String>) count2);
bundle.putStringArrayList("id2", (ArrayList<String>) id2);
bundle.putStringArrayList("sp3_1", (ArrayList<String>) title3);
bundle.putStringArrayList("sp3_2", (ArrayList<String>) count3);
bundle.putIntegerArrayList("id3", (ArrayList<Integer>) id3);
bundle.putSerializable("filter_data", data);
dialog.setArguments(bundle);
```

и вот как данные получаются в диалоге:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
title1 = Objects.requireNonNull(bundle).getStringArrayList("sp1_1");
count1 = Objects.requireNonNull(bundle).getStringArrayList("sp1_2");
title2 = Objects.requireNonNull(bundle).getStringArrayList("sp2_1");
count2 = Objects.requireNonNull(bundle).getStringArrayList("sp2_2");
title3 = Objects.requireNonNull(bundle).getStringArrayList("sp3_1");
count3 = Objects.requireNonNull(bundle).getStringArrayList("sp3_2");
ids1 = bundle.getStringArrayList("id1");
ids2 = bundle.getStringArrayList("id2");
ids3 = bundle.getStringArrayList("id3");
data = (HashMap<String, String>) bundle.getSerializable("filter_data");
```

дальше у меня в диалоге есть условие, если переменная `data` не пустой то нужно в спиннере устанавливать определенный пункт, выглядит это условие так:

```
if (!data.isEmpty()) {
spinner1.setSelection(ids1.indexOf(data.get("prof")) + 1);
spinner2.setSelection(ids2.indexOf(data.get("location")) + 1);
spinner3.setSelection(ids3.indexOf(data.get("employer"))+2);
}
```

все вроде хорошо работает, но в `spinner3` почему-то нужно добавлять +2 элемента чтобы добраться до нужного пункта вместо +1 как в предыдущих двух, и если смотреть по логам, то индекс элемента пришедшего с фрагмента равен -1. Вообще в спиннерах я добавляю по +1 потому что у меня там еще есть надпись по-умолчанию, которую нужно обходить. Я уже прошелся дебаггером по всему диалогу и по всем переменным - все приходит правильно, но почему в двух спиннерах ситуация одна, а в третьем другая? Не могу понять что там происходит.

### UPDATE

проверил только что, и добавление +2 все-равно не решило проблему, получается что у меня не находит такой элемент в hashmap хотя он там есть и другие спиннеры находят свои элементы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему впиливанием костыля. Так получается что с фрагмента я передаю в диалог массив чисел и так же передаю hashMap в котором есть число которое должно присутствовать в массиве. Так получается что я не мог найти в переданном массиве число и индекс этого числа отправлять в spinner. Вот что я в итоге сделал:

```
spinner3.setSelection(ids3.indexOf(Integer.parseInt(data.get("employer"))) + 1);
```

согласен что это оочень наверное неправильно, но в итоге работает так как нужно. Может кому-то поможет.

Answer (score 2):

Из странностей под ваше описание вижу следующее

```
bundle.putStringArrayList("id1", (ArrayList<String>) id1);
bundle.putStringArrayList("id2", (ArrayList<String>) id2);
bundle.putIntegerArrayList("id3", (ArrayList<Integer>) id3);
```

`putIntegerArrayList` и `ArrayList<Integer>` на id3

Comment: поменял, но ничего не изменилось

Comment: у меня все-равно так получается что мой список не имеет в себе элементов из hashMap, хотя это странно вообще получается